# How can i change the name of a VBA Module with python

Tags: python, excel, vba, pywin32

I'm trying to programmatically add multiple VBA Modules to an .xlsm excel file. Now the code works and adds the modules, but they are calle Module1, Module2, Module3...

How can i change the name of the Modules? I struggle to find the documentation to pywin32. And the only clue i found online did not work

```
    # open the excel wb from file
    workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(Filename=os.path.abspath(wb_path))

    # remove old vba modules
    for i in workbook.VBProject.VBComponents:
        excelModule = workbook.VBProject.VBComponents(i.Name)
        if excelModule.Type in [1, 2, 3]:
            workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove(excelModule)

    # loop through makros and attach all of them to the excel
    for makroRoot, makrodirs, makrofiles in os.walk(wb_path + '.vba'):
        for mfile in makrofiles:
            # add Module
            excelModule = workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)
            name = mfile.replace(".bas", "")
            excelModule.Name = name #does not work

            ppath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(makroRoot, mfile))
            excelModule.CodeModule.AddFromFile(ppath)
```

And i get the following error

```
...
File "add-makros.py", line 35, in merge
    excelModule.Name = name
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 549, in __setattr__
    self._oleobj_.Invoke(entry.dispid, 0, invoke_type, 0, value)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Ausnahmefehler aufgetreten.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146778156), None)
```

Comment: What is the value of `name ` variable after `mfile.replace(".bas", "")` ? If it contains spaces, it won't let you set the name for example.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! The makros i'm adding, have been exported at some point. Therefore the names should be valid. They have values like AuxContent.bas AuxFunc.bas

Comment: Does the workbook already have the module which is named similar? Exporting the module won't remove it from the workbook, from what I know. It is possible that you are adding a new module with a name, for which the module already exists in the workbook.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that was indeed the problem